# Pegando parte do telefone

Tags: c#, .net, string

No cadastro, o usuário cadastra seu telefone e este campo é com mascara (99)99999-9999 e isto é salvo no BD. se eu quiser utilizar apenas o DDD deste, e os números separados, como deveria proceder? no caso queria DDD 99 Numero 999999999. Estou utilizando MVC, precisava destes dados assim para utilizar no Controller.

Comment: O que é salvo no banco de dados é o telefone com a máscara? Então o campo é `string`?

Comment: Isso mesmo @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Primeiro substitua os caracteres especiais e depois pegue os 2 primeiros caracteres.

```
// Remove qualquer caracter que não seja numérico
numero = Regex.Replace(numero, "[^0-9]+$", "");
// Pega os 2 primeiros caracteres
ddd = numero.Substring(0, 2);
```

Comment: Regex.Replace faz a remoção do que é de caractere especial ?

Comment: Exato! Na realidade pro seu caso se a regex for só "[^0-9]+$" resolve o problema. Vou alterar

Comment: ddd = numero.Substring(0, 2)); Está fechando 2 parenteses no final, ta faltando algum, ou foi add a mais?

Comment: Estava errado mesmo, removi agora

Comment: Fiz pelo seu procedimento e deu certinho! TKS

Answer (score 9):

Usando expressões regulares, podemos fazer assim:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var teste = Regex.Match("(12) 3456-7890", @"\((\d{2})\)\s?(\d{4,5}\-?\d{4})");
// teste.Groups[0] imprime o número.
// teste.Groups[1] imprime apenas o DDD.
// teste.Groups[2] imprime apenas o número.
```

[Fiz um Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/58dlvN).

Comment: se eu quiser deixar apenas o numero sem o traço eu faço isso? 'var teste = Regex.Match("(12) 3456-7890", @"\((\d{2})\)\s?(\d{8,9})")'

Comment: Vale, mas neste caso só funciona se nunca houver o traço na máscara.

Comment: e como é ignorado este - ?

Comment: Você pode fazer um if com teste da regex e aplicar a que for conveniente ao caso.

Comment: `?`, em expressão regular, quer dizer: "zero ou uma ocorrências". Essa expressão regular que fiz, portanto, torna o uso do traço opcional.

Comment: @Sorack A vantagem deste caso é que não precisa exatamente de um if. Cada grupo representa uma informação em específico.

Comment: Então, mas justamente, o if seria para separar a versão que poderia vir sem o traço na mascara e a com o traço

Comment: @Sorack qual seria a Lógica de comparação no If?

Comment: Teria que fazer um teste de regex...

Comment: Mas pelo que o Cigano disso não precisa

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Obrigado pelas dicas que sempre dá, mas o procedimento de Sorack Funcionou melhor para meu problema, removendo o traço. Valeu

Answer (score 6):

Pra mim o mais fácil é fazer um *simples* [`SubString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_):

```
using static System.Console;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var fone = "(12)34567-8901";
        WriteLine(fone.Substring(1, 2));
        WriteLine(fone.Substring(4, 5) + fone.Substring(10, 4));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/BQRVRH). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nKolEb). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/CutAndJoin.cs).